# AngularJS directive pass parameters through templateUrl function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to move my template from being in-line to it's own file. Everything was working before I changed from template to templateUrl

```
Glenn.directive('test', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 1000,
        terminal: true,
        templateUrl: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
            return ('test.html');
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {     
            attrs.$set('editable-text', 'content.' + attrs.edit + '.data');
            attrs.$set('edit', null);
            $compile(element)(scope);
        }
    }
});
```

**test.html**

```
{{ 'content.' + tAttrs.edit + '.data' }}

<button ng-click="' + tAttrs.edit + '_form'+ '.$show()" ng-hide="' + tAttrs.edit + '_form'+ '.$visible">edit</button>
```

Why isn't the `tAttrs` being passed to my template test.html?

Comment: Can you post JSFiddle it Plunker with your code? It's hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is pass an attribute value to my template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never seen this that way, i always pass an string to the templateUrl property like

```
...
templateUrl: './foodirective.tmpl.html'
...
```

You could assign the attrs from your directive element in the linking function:

```
myApp.directive('fooDirective', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    templateUrl: './foodirective.tmpl.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      // do stuff
      scope.tAttrs = attrs;
    }
  }
})
```

I've prepared a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6Oh0l7JyKoFZif2pnHuK?p=preview) for you.

Comment: I'm not sure why this doesn't work for me. I just get null returned on my template `tAttrs.edit` :(

Comment: > All I'm trying to do is pass an attribute value to my template.

That's exactly what I'm doing in my example, did you check the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6Oh0l7JyKoFZif2pnHuK?p=preview)?